# How can I access list of objects in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this in my viewModel.

```
 public IEnumerable<TeamDto> Teams { get; set; }
```

And, in my view:

```
 <input  name="Teams" id="Teams" value=@Model.Teams />
```

How do I access the team list in jQuery?

```
 var data2 = $("#Teams")??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code on the same cshtml page in end of page.

```
@{
        IEnumerable<TeamDto> loRes = new IEnumerable<TeamDto>();
        loRes = Model.Teams;
        <script>
        console.log('@loRes.FirstOrDefault().fiedlName');
        </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You access the value of an input by using the `val()` method. You can also set the value with `val('your value')`

```js
var data2 = $("#Teams").val();
```

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't work. when I add.val() , it gives me :"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Rype.Teams.Dto.TeamDto]"  I can't see the list

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your trying to achieve here. The `val` function will return the inputs value but you need to consider what format it's in, possibly `JSON.parse` (or the jQuery equivalent) it to get data JavaScript can use.

Comment: Sorry, I read than as an error message not the actual value.... you need to get `@Model.Teams` to output in `json`, which I don't know how to do. But I believe that's your issue with accessing the object from javascript.